# QGIS 3.30.1 reprojection and style issues

Tags: coordinate-system, style

I have a map project in EPSG:4326, all layers in EPSG:4326, I need to reproject the whole map to azimuth orthogonal, but when I do so, I loose all the parameters I set on the original layers. For ex. I had expressions to show only few labels and symbols, but when I reproject all symbols are shown, and none of the labels. This has happend with both point and line layers.

I have tried to COPY/PASTE STYLE between the old and new layers, but then the whole new layer disappear.

Am I missing something or is this a bug?

Comment: Update: even if I manually apply the old parameters for symbols and layers to the new reprojected layer everything disappear. I think it's related to the unit used, if I use map units, whatever the number entered, nothing shows up, while it works if I use mm. I used map units in the old layer. So, the new question now is: any reason why a layer reprojected to azimuth orthogonal would not accept map units?

Comment: Please do not comment on your own Question. Comments exist to request clarifications. They are meant to be ephemeral. Any change to the context of the Question should be an [Edit].

Comment: Did you reproject all layers? Because instead of that, you could just define a new project CRS, than the map canvas (including all layers) will visually appear in the projection, even if the data itself is still in `EPSG:4326`. You should add a bit more details to see exactly what goes on. Sharin a simplified dummy project + data would help seeing what's going on.

Comment: When using map unit you may need to use very big or small number ( it will depend on the scale and crs unit) to get displayable result and of course you need to adjust if you reproject (1 degree of latitude is around 111000 meters so if you reproject from degree to meter you need to adjust your map unit by the same factor)